# SharedAccessSignature Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to provide 'read-only' access for my blobs via a Web Service. The Web Service has a method that takes in the Blob and Container information and then returns back a URL with the Shared Access Signature that the user can use to access the blob. Since these images (blobs) are cached on the Phone, I would like to keep the signatures valid for up to 1 day.

I am using the following code:

```
        var blobClient = GetBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        if (container != null)
        {
            container.CreateIfNotExist();
        }

        var policy = new SharedAccessPolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.Now,
            Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days)
        };

        if (permissions.Contains("w"))
        {
            policy.Permissions = policy.Permissions | SharedAccessPermissions.Write;
            policy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
        }

        //The shared access policy provides read/write access to the container for 10 hours.
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPerms = new BlobContainerPermissions();
        // The public access setting explicitly specifies that the container is private, 
        // so that it can't be accessed anonymously.
        containerPerms.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off;
        containerPerms.SharedAccessPolicies.Clear();
        containerPerms.SharedAccessPolicies.Add("mypolicy", policy);
        // Set the permission policy on the container.
        container.SetPermissions(containerPerms);

        var blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobName);
        // Get the shared access signature to share with users.
        var blobPolicy = new SharedAccessPolicy();
        blobPolicy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days);
        blobPolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read;
        string sas = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(blobPolicy, "mypolicy");

        return sas;
```

Every time I try to use this code, I get the following error:
**Signature did not match. String to sign used was r
2012-01-03T08:38:52Z
/myContainer/12100/12409/29cae1b6-2955-4a33-ab27-ff99f0bb6470_m.jpg
mypolicy**

Can anyone please guide me with this?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the issue lies in the "signature" component of your URL (the sig parameter).

The URL to access your BLOB needs to be in this form if you're using a 60 minute URL without a policy on it:

```
http://[storage account name].blob.core.windows.net/[top level container name]/[filename of BLOB]?sr=b&st=2012-01-19T12:21:40Z&se=2012-01-19T13:21:40Z&sp=r&sig=[Base-64 encoded signature]
```

Or in this form if you're using a policy:

```
http://[storage account name].blob.core.windows.net/[top level container name]/[filename of BLOB]?sr=b&st=2012-01-19T12:21:40Z&se=2012-01-19T13:21:40Z&si=[name of security policy]&sig=[Base-64 encoded signature]
```

About the signature ( sig parameter on the URL: )
Microsoft pseudocode showing how they want us to generate the signature:

```
Signature=Base64(HMAC-SHA256(UTF8(StringToSign)))
```

How do you make the string-to-sign? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx

> StringToSign = signedpermissions + "\n"
>                  + signedstart + "\n"
>                  + signedexpiry + "\n"
>                  + canonicalizedresource + "\n"
>                  + signedidentifier

The linefeeds are crucial -- these are equivalent to the hex character 0xA. Standard Java "\n" linefeeds are fine. Don't leave them out or it won't work.

It's OK for the signedpermissions to be null -- as long as you still include the linefeed after signedpermissions if it's null.

If signedpermissions is populated then it's OK for signedidentifier to be null. You don't need to put a linefeed character after it.

You MUST make sure your string is converted into UTF-8 (Unicode 8) before you run the HMAC SHA256 hash over it.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh508996.aspx

> The string-to-sign is a unique string constructed from the fields that must be verified in order to authenticate the request. The signature is an HMAC computed over the string-to-sign and key by using the SHA256 algorithm, and then encoded by using Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are setting the SAS policy completely for 'mypolicy' on the container.  Once you do that, they are not open to subsequent modification from query string params.  It is a 'fill-in-the-blank' system.  The only parts you can specify on query string are the parts not already specified and saved on container policy (i.e. filling in blanks).  So, in this case, you have

```
blobPolicy.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days);
blobPolicy.Permissions = SharedAccessPermissions.Read;
```

But, those two options were already saved on the policy, so you cannot specify them again (they are adding to resulting querystring).  If you want to specify those, you should not have them already saved on the initial SetPermission().

You can prove this by commenting out those two lines and your resulting signature should be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because a shared access signature cannot be for more than one hour. In order to have a more than one hour SAS, you need to use container level policy (that you can revoke)
Excerpt from [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1)

> One way that you can manage a Shared Access Signature is to control
>   its lifetime by ensuring that it expires within an hour. If you want
>   to continue to grant a client access to the blob after that time
>   period, you must issue a new signature. This is the behavior of a
>   Shared Access Signature that is not associated with a container-level
>   access policy. A Shared Access Signature not bound to a
>   container-level access policy cannot be revoked. If a start time is
>   specified, the expiration time must be 60 or fewer minutes from the
>   start time, or the signature is invalid and cannot be used. If no
>   start time is specified, the signature is valid only during the 60
>   minute period before the expiration time. This policy is intended to
>   minimize risk to a storage account in the event that the signature is
>   leaked.
>
> Another way to manage a Shared Access Signature is to associate the
>   signature with a container-level access policy. The container-level
>   access policy is represented by the signedidentifier field on the URL.
>   A container-level access policy provides an additional measure of
>   control over one or more Shared Access Signatures, including the
>   ability to revoke the signature if needed.